# FB SDK Version 2.4 not returning value for /me/groups

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the User's groups list with the following code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#fetchButton").click(function() {
                console.log('fetch button');
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(res){
                    if( res.status == "connected" ){ // check if logged in
                        // get user data first, which will be handled by an anonymours fucntion passed inline
                        FB.api('/me', function(meResponse) {
                            //console.log(meResponse);
                            UID = meResponse.id;

                            getGroups();

                            console.log(meResponse);
                        });
                    } else { // if not logged in, call login procedure
                        FB.login(function(){
                            $("#fetchButton").click();
                        }, {scope: 'publish_actions, publish_actions, read_stream, user_groups'});
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        function getGroups() {

            FB.api('/me/groups', function(groupResponse) {
                console.log(groupResponse);
            });

        }
```

This code used to work with some old version of FB SDK. But not now.

Any help!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Answer (score 3):

`read_stream` and `user_groups` are deprecated and you are using `publish_actions` two times. In order to get a list of all the groups you manage, you need to use `user_managed_groups` now.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: ok thanks. Then there is no way to access the group, that the user joined (but not an administrator)?

Comment: exactly, that´s what i am saying